# Blade::compileString() but return string concatination instead of inline PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I used [`Blade::extend()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_extend) to create a more complex directive than it is possible with [`Blade::directive()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-blade). After trying different approaches for hours, this is what I ended up with—and it works. Except for one thing, I'm still not entirely fine with:

When I pass `$matches['callback']` (which contains ordinary blade syntax) to the output, Blade converts a string like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('user', [ 'user' => $user ]) }}">{{ $user->username }}</a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo e(route('community.users.user', [ 'user' => $author->id ])); ?>"><?php echo e($author->username); ?></a>
```

This is done, because internally, Blade seems to use [`Blade::compileString()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compileString). That might be fine in some cases, but as you can probably see, it breaks the layout, because the whole `<a />` tag has to be `echo`'d and the inner stuff has to be concatenated like this to return valid HTML:

```
'<a href="'. route('community.users.user', [ 'user' => $author->id ]) .'">'. $author->username .'</a>'
```

As you can see, I have a workaround, to manually replace `{{` and `}}` so that string concatenation is happening, but I wonder if there's a way, to do that *properly*.

AppServiceProvider.php:

```php
Blade::extend(function($expression) {
    $pattern = '/\@mapJoin\((?<collection>.*?), \'(?<variable>.*?)\', (?<delimiter>.*?)\)(?<callback>.*?)\@endMapJoin/ms';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
        // @todo dynamic compiling
        $callback = preg_replace('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/', "'.$1.'", trim($matches["callback"]));
        return '<?php echo '.$matches['collection'].'->map(function($'.$matches['variable'].') {
            return \''.$callback.'\';
        })->join('.$matches["delimiter"].'); ?>'; //Blade::compileString()
    }, $expression);
});
```

---

I wanted to have something in my blade syntax which allows me to do the following:

```
@mapJoin($story->authors, 'author', ',')
    <!-- normal markup and blade stuff -->
@endMapJoin
```

for example:

```
@mapJoin($story->authors, 'author', ',')
    <a href="{{ route('community.users.user', [ 'user' => $author->id ]) }}">{{ $author->username }}</a>
@endMapJoin
```

to turn it into:

```php
$collection->map(function($variable) {
    return echo $callback;
})->join($delimiter);
```

which would result in:

```html
<a href="community/users/user/1">User 1</a>, <a href="community/users/user/2">User 2</a>, <a href="community/users/user/1">User 2</a>
```

`Blade::directive()` sadly only replaces the `@something` itself, not the content between, and it does not have a concept of start and end tag. I tried to address that with my solution using `Blade::extend()`. Even more general, it would be something like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler as CompilersBladeCompiler;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class BladeCompiler extends CompilersBladeCompiler
{
    public static function compileDirective(string $name, array $parameters, callable $callback)
    {
        $paramString = '';
        if (count($parameters)) {
            $paramString = '\(';
            foreach($parameters as $parameter) {
                $paramString .= '(?<'.$parameter.'>.*?)';
            }
            $paramString .= '\)';
        }
        return Blade::extend(function($expression) use($name, $paramString, $callback) {
            $pattern = '/\@'.$name.$paramString.'(?<content>.*?)\@end'.Str::studly($name).'/ms';
            return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $expression);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would explain what you are trying to accomplish first before diving into the technical aspect. For example: "I would like to implement a custom Blade directive that would turn `@mapJoin( ... )` into `xxxxx`"

Comment: @AkenRoberts I added some more explanation

Comment: Do you have a more complicated use case outside of separators? You could achieve this using standard Blade syntax `@foreach() ... @endforeach` along with the [`$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)

Comment: I could, but I don't think, foreach is the best choice for this.

Answer (score -2):

The error you are describing is not correct at all, even if it is doing so, it is not breaking `<a>` in any way...

Share what you really expect...

Instead of using `{{ }}` try `{!! !!}`, but what you are using (`{{ }}`) is correct...

Read more about [escaping strings here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data).

Comment: `{!! !!}` is definitely not needed in this case since everything between `@mapJoin()` and `@endMapJoin()` is normal markup and blade stuff as if these two directives weren't there.

Comment: "The error you are describing is not correct at all" it is, I've seen it. Maybe we are at cross purposes.

Comment: @shaedrich sorry, I misread your question, as you did not include an example (new part after the line), so my personal opinion/recommendation would be to: 1) use [`components`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#components) instead of directives or 2) create a simple Service class (it does not extend anything) and have that logic inside a method, so you call that service in the view and done or 3) use a [`view composer`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers), but do not use `Blade::extend()`, it will not help you.